# Change link colour at top of screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code which applies a class when user is at the top of screen

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill');
    $('...').addClass('...');
  } else {
    $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill');
    $('...').removeClass('...');
  }
});
```

css

```
#anim-nav {
position: fixed; 
-webkit-transition: background 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: background 0.35s ease;
-ms-transition: background 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: background 0.35s ease;
transition: background 0.35s ease;
}

.bg-fill { background: #fff; }

.screen-nav li a {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

When .bg-fill gets added to #anim-nav I want the a links to be white, when the class is removed it returns to black. They are currently in default black.

I figure I can do it in a similar way by adding and removing a class ( the '...' areas, but can't figure it out since I need to set a colour to the text

Comment: Do u have a fiddle or site or provide ur html?

Comment: Which links should be coloured white? Are they inside `#anim-nav`?

Comment: are you trying to color the text to white over white background `.bg-fill`..?

Comment: I want the text white when there is no background, because at the top of the screen the navigation is overtop an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to know the html structure to apply correctly. If the navigation links comes under the `bg-fill` then you can apply like below. No need of Add/Remove of additional class in Jquery.

```
.bg-fill .screen-nav li a {
     color:#fff;
}
```